# Android check permission before Main activity

Tags: android, android-permissions

on my app i have implemented a splash activity that check if is first run app and if is true show a dialog message, this is the code:

```
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        myLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    }
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);
    if (isFirstStart) {
        android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(splashscreen.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_intro_sms));
        alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.intro_sms));
        alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();

        SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();
        e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
        e.apply();
    } else {

        startApp();
    }
}
```

When dialog are show if click ok i open MainActivity. Now after 'Ok' click into dialog befor to start MainActivity i would like to show a dialog request permission.
I have create a abstract class for this and i call in this way:

```
requestAppPermissions(new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                R.string.msg,REQUEST_PERMISSION);
```

Now i set this line code into OnCreate the permission request are show before the splash activity but if i set into onClick methos of 'ok' allert dialog is not show.

How i can show the permission request after click ok befor to start Main Activity?
Any help is great
Thanks

I have integrate my onRequestPermissionresult into abstract class in this way:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    for(int permisson : grantResults) {
        permissionCheck = permissionCheck + permisson;
    }

    if( (grantResults.length > 0) && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permissionCheck) {
        onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //start activity
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        //Display message when contain some Dangerous permisson not accept
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), mErrorString.get(requestCode),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }).show();
    }
}
```

and the message permission are show after ok click but after the app close and not open MainActivity

i have change my splashcrenn and i have set all method about permsion into it, this is code:

```
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode) {

}

public void requestAppPermissions(final String[]requestedPermissions, final int stringId, final int requestCode) {
    mErrorString.put(requestCode, stringId);

    int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    boolean showRequestPermissions = false;
    for(String permission: requestedPermissions) {
        permissionCheck = permissionCheck + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        showRequestPermissions = showRequestPermissions || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission);
    }

    if (permissionCheck!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if(showRequestPermissions) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), stringId, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(splashscreen.this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
                }
            }).show();
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class); //start activity
                splashscreen.this.startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

into dialog 'ok' click button i have set this:

```
alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(splashscreen.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

                        /*Intent i = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);*/

                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
```

but when i click ok the app close and not open MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

show permission dialog in button click:

```
alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1); //show reuest dialog

                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Now catch the result in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and start your `MainActivity`

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class); //start activity
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
 }
```

in your abstract class pass your activity context and use it to start `MainActivity`

To pass context:

```
    class YourAbstractClass{

// variable to hold context
private Context context;

//save the context recievied via constructor in a local variable

public YourAbstractClass(Context context){  //constructor
    this.context=context;
  }
}
```

In your splash Activity call your Abstract class like:

```
YourAbstractClass class = new YourAbstractClass(this); //pass context
```

Now use the context to `startActivity`

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I have change my post with a response about your help

Comment: you have to pass your `splash activity` context to your Abstract class and start activity using that context

Comment: on my splash screen i have use this Activity activity = (Activity) context; is correct?

Comment: I have implemente the custructor into abstract class and after in the splash activity i must implement public class Splash(Context context){super(context)} but when i run app i have a crash: error has no zero argument constructor

Comment: @APPGIS create a dummy contructor like: `public your_class() {
    // No args constructor
}`

Comment: Hi have change my code as you can see on my post, but the MainActivity not start

Comment: start your mainactivity in `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Comment: I do this, if you see my post you could see that i start MainActivity in this way: Intent i = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class); //start activity
                splashscreen.this.startActivity(i);

Comment: is the toast message printed when u allow the permission dialog?

Comment: your `onRequestPermissionsResult` should be  in the same activity where u write `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);`

Comment: onRequestPermissionResult is in the same Activity. When i accept permission the toast message not show. So i thisnk that i doesn't take this methid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135283/discussion-between-appgis-and-rafsanahmad007).

Answer (score 0):

Request the permission after you click ok, but don't start the activity right away. Wait for the result in onRequestPermissionResult, and start your `MainActivity` there.

Comment: Can you share a example?

Comment: Well just request your permissions normally as you would in 'ok' click but don't call startActivity. When you receive the result in onRequestPermissionResult call `startActivity(context, MainActivity.class)`

Answer (score 0):

**Use if-else statement** in your button call.

> If you already have permission then execute the MainActivity call in
>   if part. If not then ask for permission in else part of if-else.

Now use **OnRequestPermissionResult** method to which is called when permissions are granted or denied. If permissions are granted in this method then again execute the MainActivity call or else just do what you need to do when permission denied like show him the reason why you need permission and try again or just exit.

Hope it helped. For everything about permissions in android in a simplified version just click [HERE (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidPermissions/article.html)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidPermissions/article.html).